# SQL - Query for array elements inside hash in json

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I have a table with a jsonb column of the below given structure.

> my_json: {"records": [{"id":1, "name":"first"}, {"id":2, "name":"second"}, {"id":3, "name":"third"}]}

What i need is select all the ids present inside the records key. And I couldn't find any help anywhere for this json structure.

I have tried for the following queries, but couldn't actually get to a point that i want to reach.

```
"select my_json->>'records' from my_table where my_json->>'records' is not null AND my_json #> '{records}' != '[]'"
```

this actually gives the complete array, but what i need is the value of all the 'id' key in that.

could somebody help in sorting it out please.

Note: I use Postgres 9.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you look for `json_array_elements`:

```
t=# with c(my_json) as (values (' {"records": [{"id":1, "name":"first"}, {"id":2, "name":"second"}, {"id":3, "name":"third"}]}'::json))
select json_array_elements(my_json->'records')->>'id' from c;
 ?column?
----------
 1
 2
 3
(3 rows)
```

Comment: I get **_PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  function json_array_elements(jsonb) does not exist_** error when executing `select json_array_elements(my_json->'records')->>'id' from my_table where my_json->>'records' is not null AND my_json #> '{records}' != '[]'`

Comment: because you said `json` in post, not `jsonb`, for the latter use `jsonb_array_elements` function...